# Using back stack

Tags: android-fragments, android-studio, back-stack

So I'm kind of a newbie in android. And I'm trying to figure out how I use back stack.
I've searched allot of content online but nothing seemed to answer me, or perhaps I can't understand most of it.
First I go from the main activity to a new fragment.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, Form.newInstance(), Form.TAG).addToBackStack(Form.TAG).commit();
}
```

And then I'm trying to make it so that when I click a button a new fragment show and when I'm done with it and I press the back button it's supposed to go back to the fragment I had first created "Form". But it doesn't do that. This is the code I use and it isn't working.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == univ) {
            Fragment fragment = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Form.TAG);
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, Uni.newInstance(), Uni.TAG).addToBackStack(Form.TAG).commit();

    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to use the "back button" on an implemented one

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. I'm trying to create a new fragment (uni) and then go back to the one I was at (form) with the back button yes, but not using an event, using the backstack, tho an event using the back button would probably also work I don't know how to do it either.